# Read Json in swift

Tags: json, swift, xcode

Hi the question is  i want to read  the **rows** in this JSON is an Array, **data** is the headboard

```
>data: {..}
     >rows  [..]
           -dataA: "Hi"
           -dataB: "Hello"
```

im  using :

```
    if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) {
        if let information = json as? [String : Any]{
                                    
               let data = information["data"] as? [String : Any]
               let rowsN = information["rows"] as? [[String : Any]]

    for datab in rowsN{
                                    let dataA = datab ["dataA"] as? String ?? ""
                                    let dataB = datab ["dataB"] as? String ?? ""

                                   print(dataA, dataB)
                                }
```

Why is not working?, i think is cause  rows is not a headboard, in that case , How could I do it?

Comment: let rowsN = information["rows"] as? [[String : Any]] should be let rowsN = data["rows"] as? [[String : Any]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`let rowsN = information["rows"] as? [[String : Any]]` - seems to be the buggy line of code.
As per your example, rows are within data. So you should be trying data["rows"] and not information["rows"].

`let rowsN = data["rows"] as? [[String : Any]]`

Hope this clarifies

```
let str = """
    {
        "data": {
            "rows": [
                {"dataA": "Hi"},
                {"dataB": "Hello"}
            ]
        }
    }
"""
let data = Data(str.utf8)
if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) {
    if let information = json as? [String : Any] {
        if let data = information["data"] as? [String : Any] {
            if let rowsN = data["rows"] as? [[String : Any]] {
                for datab in rowsN {
                    let dataA = datab ["dataA"] as? String ?? ""
                    let dataB = datab ["dataB"] as? String ?? ""
                    print(dataA)
                    print(dataB)
                }
            } else {
                print("could not load rows")
            }
        } else {
            print("could not load data")
        }
    } else {
        print("could not load json as map")
    }
} else {
    print("could not load json as map")
}
```

I personally would use a Model class and use JSON Decoder in swift for this. The API you are using is the older Objective C based one.

Comment: Thank , this works and clarified it for me , and  i'm going to investigate what you told me  :)

Comment: Great. Thanks for confirming